# Run time Error while uploading images for ASP.Net MVC APP (AWS-EBS)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My end goal is to save the file into remote Content directory in AWS-EC2 windows instance. The destination folder is  *"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Content"*  in remote server.For which i am using

```
string serveradd=Server.MapPath("/");
```

I am assuming that above command will automatically get the remote server root address. is my assumption a wrong one.

post building the project with below code i still get an runtime error

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult addimage(int? id, Image im, HttpPostedFileBase imagepath)
{             
         string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imagepath.FileName);
         string extension = Path.GetExtension(imagepath.FileName);
         filename = filename + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssff") +extension;
         string serveradd=Server.MapPath("/");
         string remotepath = Path.Combine(serveradd,filename); 
         imagepath.SaveAs(remotepath);
}
```

[image]

Here is the [link](http://pms-dev.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/Product/addimage) i am using temporarily

Comment: It may have permission issue to save image on server